# How to make a template-dependent typedef more convenient?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have several classes with all the same template arguments. They use `OftenUsedType` which is also a template. So I `typedef` it to `R` to have more convenient notation:

```
template <class T, int A, int B>
class Obj{
   typedef OftenUsedType<T, A, B> R;
}
```

Unfortunately, I have to do this in all classes which use `OftenUsedType`, since it depends on the template parameters.

The only way to make this a bit more convenient is to do the `typedef` in a class and inherit it to all classes which use it:

```
template <class T, int A, int B>
class ObjTypedef{
   typedef OftenUsedType<T, A, B> R;
}

template <class T, int A, int B>
class Obj : public ObjTypedef<T, A, B>{
}
```

But I still have to inherit the typedef class into all classes which use the type...

Is there a more convenient, good-style way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If C++11 is acceptable, you could use an alias template, which has a much more natural syntax:

```
template <class T, int A, int B>
using R = OftenUsedType<T,A,B>;
```

Comment: But as far as I see, I will still have to write `R<T, A, B>`?

Comment: Yes. If that's too much for you, you could define a macro, although it's a pretty ugly solution.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd do is replace your `int A` and `int B` with

```
template<int I>
using int_t = std::integral_constant<int, I>;
```

so that all of your templates are types.  You can get the value of the integer by `constexpr` constructing and using the `constexpr` `operator()`.

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type=typename Tag::type;

template<template<class...>class Z, class T>
struct transcribe;

template<template<class...>class Z, template<class...>class T, class...Ts>
struct transcribe<Z,T<Ts...>>:tag<Z<Ts...>> {};

template<template<class...>class Z, class T>
using transcribe_t = type<transcribe<Z,T>>;
```

`transcribe` takes a template and an instance of some other template, and transcribes the arguments to the second instance's template into the first template, returning the result.  We then leverage this in order to extract the arguments of the enclosing class, and create an `OftenUsedType` from it:

```
template<class T>
using often = transcribe_t< OftenUsedType, T >;
```

and now:

```
template<class T, class iA, class iB>
class Obj {
  using R = often<Obj>;
};
```

will result in `often<Obj>` being `OftenUsedType<T,iA,iB>`.  The `using` is optional -- you can just `often<Obj>` within `Obj` and get `OftenUsedType<T,iA,iB>`.

This can be done without converting all of your template arguments to classes.  It just requires a different (and uglier) transcribe:

```
template<template<class, int, int>class Z, class T>
struct transcribe;
template<template<class, int, int>class Z,
  template<class, int, int>class T,
  class X, int A, int B>
struct transcribe<Z, T<X,A,B>>:tag<Z<X,A,B>> {};
template<template<class, int, int>class Z, class T>
using transcribe_t=type<transcribe<Z,T>>;
```

that has to be hand-coded for each pattern of type/scalars.  Which makes me sad.

Comment: This is both horrifying and beautiful +1

Answer (score 0):

with a little boiler-template work, you can remove the need to repeat the `<T, A, B>`.

There are 2 methods here, one is to deduce the return type of a template function using decltype, the other is to simply use auto and use the template factory function to generate your often_used object.

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, int A, int B>
struct OftenUsedType
{
    OftenUsedType()
    : _mode { "none" }
    {}

    OftenUsedType(std::string mode)
    : _mode { std::move(mode) }
    {}

    template<class I>
    OftenUsedType(std::string mode, I i)
    : _mode { mode + " " + std::to_string(i) }
    {}

    void frequent_method()
    {
        std::cout << "frequent method called with mode: " << _mode << " with " << T::name << " " << A << ", " << B << std::endl;
    }

    std::string _mode;
};

// deduces T, A and B from the type of the parameter passed
// and constructs the appropriate OftenUsedType
// with supplied paramters
template<template<typename, int, int> class Object, class T, int A, int B, class...Args>
OftenUsedType<T, A, B> make_often_used(const Object<T, A, B>&, Args&& ...args)
{
    return OftenUsedType<T, A, B> { std::forward<Args>(args)... };
}


template <class T, int A, int B>
class Obj{


    using R = decltype(make_often_used(std::declval<Obj>()));

    // example of using R as a member
    R _my_r;

public:
    // example of using factor function based on argument deduction
    void method()
    {
        auto often_used_object = make_often_used(*this);
        often_used_object.frequent_method();

        auto o2 = make_often_used(*this, "alpha");
        o2.frequent_method();

        auto o3 = make_often_used(*this, "alpha", 6);
        o3.frequent_method();
    }

private:
};

struct X {
    static const std::string name;
};
const std::string X::name { "X" };

struct Y {
    static const std::string name;
};
const std::string Y::name { "Y" };

int main()
{
    Obj<X, 1, 2> x12;
    Obj<Y, 6, 3> y63;
    x12.method();
    y63.method();

    return 0;
}
```